# Retaining URL Alias without removing when modified nodes or run bulk update

Tags: path-aliases

I want to keep the old aliases when I have modified the content. I don't want the alias to be modified/removed. This is very import point in SEO perspective. How do I do this?

**Update:** I apologize if my question was not clear. I was under impression that its drupal naturally handles the aliases whenever I add/edit/update nodes and I was thinking experienced durpal community already know about this and help me. But I came to know it from gisli's comment that autopath is the module which is doing it and it has the settings how it handles it which I completly missed when I saw settings tab.

Comment: Can't know the exact reason, but read [this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The path or alias doesn't change in Drupal when you *modify* content (unless you use some module, e.g. pathauto, that do this because you've set it up to do so).  So you should not need to do *anything* to keep aliases when you've have modified the content.  If you find that aliases change when you modify content, you need to explain your use case in more detail to get this answered.

Comment: You answered my question gisle. I was thinking its the drupal core module handling it and more over I missed the option in the settings. Please add answer I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path or alias doesn't change in Drupal when you modify content.  There are, however, modules that you can install (such as [PathAuto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto)) that may do this. If this is what is breaking your aliases when content is changed/updated, you need to turn such modules off or tune their settings to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the modules [Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) and [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) will be helpful for you.

The modules have some good functionality concerning redirects SEO-wise. I have not evaluated them extensively, but they seem quite popular.

Comment: I dont see anything usefull with these modules. I can do much more with Alias Url itself. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Redirect module sets up a 301 redirect from OLD alias to NEW one when a node's alias changes... i think