# alias url to root

Tags: path-aliases

I was looking at `admin/config/search/` for adding url aliases. I wanted to add alias to the website/root so user can see same content to `mysite.com/somecityname` to same `mysite.com/`.

It seems like we can give alias to nodes only because the "Existing System Path". Is it possible at all? I guess there is a way to do this by defining it in `.htaccess` which is out of scope of Drupal, so I was wondering is there any way to achieve this?

I tried to give an alias to  which is home page but it still shows 404

Comment: This question is quite similar to your previous one and I believe my answer is applicable to both: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105092/retaining-url-alias-without-removing-when-modified-nodes-or-run-bulk-update/105098#105098

Comment: one answer for two different questions :)

Comment: that question was about managing url aliases. may be little related but it go no solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't alias something to an empty path, you can alias something to `node` (i.e. `mysite.com/node`, which will be your website root in a Drupal system set up by default).

If you're set your website root to be some *other* path than `node`, you should be able to use that path instead. Navigate to *Home » Administration » Configuration » System*, and notice what is in indicated in the text field "Default front page".  If this field is *not* empty, you must use that as your path instead of `node`.

(The above solution uses the standard path alias function that is part of Drupal core - it doesn't require any external modules.)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I think I am getting close. After giving mysite.com/mycity to mysite.com/node its not showing the home page content but some random content. How to correct this?

Comment: you are great. I have more questions :) but I will try out first